# How to patch a binary file and save it?

Tags: disassembly, patching, binary-editing

I have an ARM executable binary file and I want to patch it at precise virtual addresses. Is there any safe (and automated) way to perform this task ?

Any scripts or tools are welcome!

Comment: You need to know information about the .text because the executable code is classicaly store in this section if the binary is not obsucated or custom compiled. I think you need to learn about what is a binary file and how it is loaded in memory.

Comment: I talking about embedded my binary not run on linux/windows

Comment: But there is no OS in your  embedded system? Expose the system entirely? Maybe you are working with a firmware, if it document, learn about what is the file format of the binary and how it is loaded in memory, the basic !! If there is not doc, it's more hard and time consuming, full reverse

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux a simple group of commands as `readelf`, `printf()` and `dd` can do the job.

For example, if you have the binary `MyBin` in ELF format and you want to patch the following condition located at `0x418966` in memory :

```
jnz     loc_418706 ; 0x418966: 0f 85 9a fd ff ff
```

Firstly you must to find information about the `.text` section of the binary file:

```
$ readelf --wide -S MyBin | grep '.text\|Name\|Off'
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000414670 014670 0dfa82 00  AX  0   0 16
```

Here:

- the `.text` section start in the binary file at `0x014670`;
- the `.text` section is loaded in memory at `0x414670`.

Then you must compute the instruction offset in the binary file relative to the `.text` section:

```
0x418966 - 0x414670 = 0x0042f6
0x014670 + 0x0042f6 = 0x018966
```

Or with a shell one-liner:

```
$ text_addr=0000000000414670; inst_addr=418966; text_off=014670; \
  python -c 'print(0x'$inst_addr' - 0x'$text_addr' + 0x'$text_off')'
100710
```

Here the instruction to patch is located at `0x18966` in the binary file.

Finally, I patch the binary with a nop and a near jump (`jmp e9 [cd]`).

```
printf '\x90\xe9' | dd of=MyBin bs=1 seek=100710 count=3 conv=notrunc
```

Comment: why do I need the  .text section?  do you know tool for windows?